# Integration of Sqrt of polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the following:

$$\int_{12.89}^{31.10} \sqrt{-x^2+44x-384} \ dx$$

I'd appreciate it if the working out are accompanied by an explanation. I've seen some explanations in the web. However, their textbook nature allows the numbers to work out properly by common methods like trig substitution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rearrange the expression inside:

$-x^2+44x-384=-(x^2-44x+384)=-(x^2-44x+484-100)=-((x-22)^2-100)=100-(x-22)^2$

This gives you a good idea of what to do for your substitution.

$$\int_{12.89}^{31.10} \sqrt{100-(x-22)^2} \ dx$$

Let $x=22+10\sin t$ hence $dx=10\cos t \ dt$

When $x=12.89$ then $t=-\arcsin0.911$ and when $x=31.10$ then $t=\arcsin0.91$ so your integral becomes:

$$\int_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91} \sqrt{100-100\sin^2 t}\times 10\cos t \ dt$$
$$=\int_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91} 100\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}\cos t \ dt$$
$$=\int_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91} 100\cos^2 t \ dt$$
$$=\int_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91} 100\cos^2 t \ dt$$
$$=\int_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91} 50(1+\cos2t) \ dt$$
$$=\bigg(50t+25\sin2t\bigg)_{-\arcsin0.911}^{\arcsin0.91}$$
$$=50(\arcsin0.911+\arcsin0.91)+50\times0.911\sqrt{1-0.911^2}+50\times0.91\sqrt{1-0.91^2}$$
$$\approx152.099$$

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try to digest it :)

Comment: Sorry, how do you decide that x = 22 + 10sin(t)?

Comment: Under the square root you want to get the form $(a^2-a^2\sin^2t)$. I worked backwards from there. So let $100-(x-22)^2=a^2-a^2\sin^2t$. Hence $a^2=100$ and $100\sin^2t=(x-22)^2$ and so $x-22=10\sin t$ which lets to the specific substitution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Is there a special term for that form or method? Is it related to this : http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/3/txe3db3h.htm

Comment: In my head they are fall under the category of Trigonometric Substitutions (which also includes other techniques). I'm not sure if this specific technique has a name.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I mean, why do i need to have that form? I apologize for my repetitive questions.

Comment: The square root makes the integral difficult to evaluate so the technique helps remove that from the integral as it allows you to change $\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2t}=\sqrt{a^2(1-\sin^2t)}=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t}=a\cos t$

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you very much for guiding me in this question

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$-x^2+44x-384=10^2-(x-22)^2$$

Can you try to come up with a suitable substitution now?

Comment: Thank you very much. Such as the indirect substitution method?